# How can I add the same XML tags multiple times, with different content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, tags

I have some problems with my code. I want to create an XML Document with JQuery / JavaScript. I am now at the point, where I want to create a few  Tags and populate them each with the same tags but different content inside the tags.

Here is the code for better understand

```
function setItems(xmlDoc, channelTag){
        const itemList = [];

        const itemTitle = xmlDoc.createElement("title");
        const itemLink = xmlDoc.createElement("link");
        const itemGuid = xmlDoc.createElement("guid");
        const itemMediaContent = xmlDoc.createElement("media:content");
        const itemMediaDescription = xmlDoc.createElement("media:description");

        itemList.push(itemTitle, itemLink, itemGuid, itemMediaContent, itemMediaDescription);

        for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++){

            var item = xmlDoc.createElement("item");
            channelTag.appendChild(item);

            //Populate the <item> with the tags from "itemList" and content from "jsonObj"
            $.each(itemList, function(index) {

                $(channelTag).children('item')[i].appendChild(itemList[index]).textContent = jsonObj[0].title;
            })

        }   
    }
```

The Output of the code looks like this:

```
<item></item>
<item></item>
<item>
 <title>Something</title>
 <guid>Something</guid>
 <link>Something</link>
 <media:content>Something</media:description>
 <media:description>Something</media:description>
</item>
```

It always populates the last item-Tag but not the ones above. What I want is that every item-Tag has the same child-Tags (e.g. title, link, guid and so on). Is there something i am missing some unique tags or something like that?

Edited:
Here is some minimal HTML and XML. The values for the function "xmlDoc" and "channelTag" just contains some Document Elements, where my items should be appended, like so:

```
<rss>
  <channel>
    <title>SomeTitle</title>
    <atom:link href="Link" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/> 
    <link>SomeLink</link>
    <description>SomeDesc</description>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
</channel>
</rss>



 <div class="col-5 col-sm-5 col-lg-3 order-2 count">
       <a class="guid1"><img class="card-img image1"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-7 col-sm-7 col-lg-5 order-2">
         <div class="card-body">
            <a class="guid1">
              <h5 class="card-title title1 overflow-title"></h5>
            </a>
           <p class="card-text body1 text-body overflow-body"></p>
         <div class="card-body subtitle">                                                                                  
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you add a call example to  **setItems** plus a minimal html body component?

Comment: i edited some HTML and a few more information, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code but the area we mostly want to focus on is this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++){
    var item = xmlDoc.createElement("item");
    channelTag.appendChild(item); // you're adding a node here
    $.each(itemList, function(index) {
        $(channelTag).children('item')[i].appendChild(... // and here
    })
}
```

Instead of appending nodes multiple times per iteration, you should create and populate your node before add it it to channelTag.

Here's a way your could do it:

```
// use a "$" sign as a variable name prefix, so you know it's a Document Element and not a regular javascript variable
var $item = xmlDoc.createElement("item");
// you don't need jQuery for this iteration
itemList.forEach(function (item, index) {
  $item.appendChild(itemList[index]).textContent = jsonObj[0].title;
});
// if "channelTag" is a Document Element, rename it "$channelTag"
$channelTag.appendChild(item);
```

Couple things about the code above:

- you don't need jQuery, use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead
- there is no way telling what type is channelTag. If it is a selector (of type string), use `$(selector)`, but you are using the `appendChild()` method before, suggesting it's actually a Document Element. In that case you don't need to wrap it with `$()`

I don't have the context needed to test this code, so no guarantee it'll work out of the box. But try and re-read your code and go through it top-to-bottom. For each variable, describe its type and value. I found that to be helpful when I'm lost in code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. channelTag just contains <channel></channel> with a few other tags within it. For better understanding, I want to create a RSS Feed File, and channelTag is just the outer tags. I will try to rebuild the code with your Input.

Comment: The code works and I think i am getting a better understanding of all those things, but my problem still persists that the tag inside an item-Tag e.g. < title > only gets set only in the last item-Tag and not the ones above and I dont understand why

Comment: Did you try to break up this code? `$item.appendChild(itemList[index]).textContent = jsonObj[0].title;` By the looks of it, you may have an unexpected [pass-by-reference](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-pass-by-value/) situation going on.

Comment: I found another way around. I just had to use $item.cloneNode(true), after populating my item-Tag with the necessary children-tags, so every item-Tag had the desired childNodes.